# Does the converse of angle bisector theorem true?

Tags: geometry

My question is clearly stated in the title.

By that theorem, I am not referring to the one saying “points on the angle bisector of an angle are equidistant from the sides”. It is the one that divides the opposite side instead.

The proof is not that difficult (I think!) but I find it was hardly mentioned. Even using “converse of angle bisector theorem” as search keyword in WIKI, the reply is “The page …. does not exist.”

Comment: What do you mean by "divides the opposite side" in your question? As in an equilateral triangle, angle bisectors will bisect the side opposite the angle, but there are clear counterexamples if this is not what you mean (e.g., a square).

Comment: I think he's talking about triangles. But as you've said, i don't understand the question myself.

Comment: @SwapnilTri: Yes, I believe he is asking: given a triangle, does any angle bisector necessarily bisect the side opposite the angle? However, his wording isn't very clear to me, and I don't like to answer unintended questions. :)

Comment: @Clayton : I can imagine a triangle in my head, where a side bisector (or whatever the correct terminology is) is not an angle bisector. So that contradicts both necessary and sufficient parts.

Comment: The theorem in (the not-so-clearly-stated) question is probably this: In $\triangle ABC$ with $D$ on $BC$ such that $AD$ bisects $\angle A$, $$\frac{|BD|}{|CD|} = \frac{|BA|}{|CA|}$$ The easiest proof involves a simple application of the Law of Sines that can be reversed (with a very minor disclaimer), so the converse holds.

Comment: This replies to all the comments given above. 1) I thought the ‘angle bisector theorem’ is commonly well-known and that is why I’ve it stated in a brief way. 2) It involves a triangle (NOT a square), and the opposite side [wrt the angle in question] is being divided (NOT bisected). 3) Thanking @blue for stating it more clearly for me and providing one the result that I want. 4) The remaining part that I want to ask is “why is this fact seldom mentioned” (for example, some proved the theorem itself but said nothing about its converse). 5) Sorry for the confusion caused and the late reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the proof in [Classical Geometry: Euclidean, Transformational, Inversive, and Projective](https://kimhongsim.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/classical-geometry-euclidean-transformational-inversive-and-projective-gnv64.pdf), page 144. It uses corollary 5.2.4:

> If $B$, $C$, and $D$ are collinear points and if $A$ is a point not collinear with them, then $$\frac{[ABD]}{[ADC]}=\frac{BD}{DC}\;.$$

[image]

as follows:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So to be explicit about the question you ask, here is this converse theorem as I understand it:

> Given a triangle $\triangle ABC$ and a point $D$ on $BC$ which satisfies $$\frac{\lvert BD\rvert}{\lvert DC\rvert}=\frac{\lvert AB\rvert}{\lvert AC\rvert}\;.$$ Then the line $AD$ will be a bisector of the angle $\angle CAB$.

Is this the theorem which you want to have verified?

Well, take the forward direction: starting at the angle bisector, you know there is a point $D'$ which satisfies the equation above. So the question you have to ask yourself is this: given one point which does satisfy the equation, can there be another?

You can consider the line $BC$ as a real projective axis, with $C$ as its zero point and $B$ as it's one point. So the condition

$$\frac{\lvert BD\rvert}{\lvert DC\rvert}=a$$

(where $a$ is fixed) translates into

$$\frac{\lvert 1-x\rvert}{\lvert x\rvert}=a$$

If you omit the absolute value signs, then either numerator and denominator have the same sign, in which case the right hand side should still read $a$. Or they have different signs, in which case the right hand side would become $-a$. So here you have

$$\frac{1-x}{x}=\pm a
\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad
x=\frac{1}{1\pm a}$$

So there is indeed a second solution, one where $x$ is between $0$ and $1$ and one where it is smaller than zero or greater than one. So there is a second point $D$ which is not equal to the $D'$ on the inner angle bisector, which does not lie on the segment $BC$, but which does lie on the extended line $BC$ and which does satisfy the above equation.

With a bit more work, again along the lines of the [Wikipedia proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem#Proof), you can show that this second point is the point where the line $BC$ intersects the exterior angle bisector.

So the theorem as stated above is true as long as you either restrict “point $D$ on $BC$” to mean “point $D$ on the line *segment* $BC$” or interpret the conclusion as “$AD$ will be an *inner or outer* bisector of the angle $\angle CAB$”.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis that has answered part of my question. The ‘commonly known’ angle bisector theorem is the “weaker’ one that with “point D on the line segment BC”. My other question is “why is this fact seldom mentioned” (for example, some proved the theorem itself but said nothing about its converse). Is it because it has no usable value? Or ….

Comment: @Mick: I could only speculate about that.